# Where to get the publisher account id to be added to add it to app-ads.txt?

Tags: flutter, facebook

I've added Facebook login to my flutter app and its working before the new Facebook requires [app-ads.txt](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/mobile-app-verification). Recent changes requires me to create an app-ads.txt. My question is where do I find my publisher account id? Do I have to create it?  My app was already uploaded to the google Playstore and Appstore. Facebook login will not work until I've added app-ads.txt.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put **app-ads.txt.** at your server name and then app-ads.txt genrate file and the the code given by them

eg.
https://yourseverserver.com/app-ads.txt
in app-ads.txt.
just simple code given by your advertiser // pub- ca- 000